# cfoutput inside cfoutput

Tags: sql, join, coldfusion

i want to create a table with product list with its each product, its price list, but the problem is that i cant join two queries, because i want one output to be inserted in another output, but it is impossible to achieve just putting them in this way, i know that i have to join 2 sql queries in order to make them work properly, plus for each product have 4 prices, anyway, to make it more clear i made a screenshot the way i want it to see: http://s44.radikal.ru/i106/1108/57/33380d0557f4.jpg and here is the queries:

**Product query:**

```
<cfquery name="get_products" datasource="#dsn3#">   SELECT DISTINCT P.*,PS.MONEY,PS.PRICE   FROM PRODUCT P,PRICE_STANDART PS    WHERE       P.IS_SALES=1        AND P.IS_PURCHASE=1         AND P.IS_INTERNET=1         AND P.PRODUCT_ID=PS.PRODUCT_ID      AND PS.PURCHASESALES=1      AND PS.PRICESTANDART_STATUS=1       <cfif len(trim(attributes.product_cat)) and len(attributes.product_code)>           AND P.PRODUCT_CODE LIKE '#attributes.product_code#%'        </cfif>         <cfif isdefined('attributes.product_id') and len(attributes.product_id)>            AND P.PRODUCT_ID=#attributes.product_id#        </cfif>     ORDER BY PS.PRICE DESC </cfquery>
```

**Price query:**

```
<cfquery name="get_prices" datasource="#dsn3#">
        SELECT PRICE, PRODUCT_ID FROM PRICE WHERE PRODUCT_ID = #PRODUCT_ID#
    </cfquery>
```

**and the table:**

```
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" class="color-border" width="100%">
    <tr class="color-header">
        <td width="30" class="header_bold">No</td>
        <td><b>Ürün</b></td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="80">Liste fiyatı</td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="80">Bayı 1</td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="80">Bayı 2</td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="80">Bayı 3</td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="80">Bayı 4</td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="25">Para</td>
    </tr>
    <cfoutput query="get_products" startrow="#attributes.startrow#" maxrows="#attributes.maxrows#">
        <tr height="20" onMouseOver="this.className='color-light';" onMouseOut="this.className='color-row';" class="color-row">
            <td>#currentrow#</td>
            <td>#product_name#</td>
            <td>#tlformat(price,2)#</td>
            <td>#tlformat((price*0.5),2)#</td> <!---this is fixed price! --->
            <td>#tlformat((price*0.49),2)#</td> <!---this is fixed price! --->
            <td>#tlformat((price*0.475),2)#</td> <!---this is fixed price! --->
            <td>#tlformat((price*0.45),2)#</td> <!---this is fixed price! --->
            <td align="center">#MONEY#</td>
        </tr>
    </cfoutput>
</table>
```

the explanation "this is fixed price!" means i inserted them and counted it by my own, but it should be changed from the prices list i want to integrate, but i can't...
thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really should do a join on the queries:

```
<cfquery name="get_products" datasource="#dsn3#">   
SELECT DISTINCT P.*,PS.MONEY,PS.PRICE   
FROM PRODUCT P
JOIN PRICE_STANDART PS ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PS.PRODUCT_ID
JOIN PRICE PR ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PR.PRODUCT_ID  
WHERE       
P.IS_SALES=1        
AND P.IS_PURCHASE=1         
AND P.IS_INTERNET=1               
AND PS.PURCHASESALES=1      
AND PS.PRICESTANDART_STATUS=1       
<cfif len(trim(attributes.product_cat)) and len(attributes.product_code)>           
  AND P.PRODUCT_CODE LIKE '#attributes.product_code#%'        
</cfif>         
<cfif isdefined('attributes.product_id') and len(attributes.product_id)>            
   AND P.PRODUCT_ID=#attributes.product_id#        
</cfif>     
ORDER BY PS.PRICE DESC 
</cfquery>
```

If the PRICE table returns more than one price for each product, you could then use the GROUP attribute of . For more info on that, take a look here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ff6.html

Comment: how do i use this group, at first i thoought its working, but it didnt, there are multiple products, with one price, i want one product with multiple prices, i think i must use group, but how?!

Comment: You need to sort the query by the product_code, and then add `group="product_code"` to your `cfquery` tag. *Then*, you need to add another `<cfoutput>` tag (with no attributes) around the price that you want to repeat. Definitely do some reading up on the group attribute of the `<cfoutput>` tag, and you'll be good to go.